# R: Remove dataframe elements that contain a specific character

Tags: r, dataframe

A dataframe includes strings that contain a specific character (such as “<”):

```
DF <- data.frame(c(1,"<2",3),c("< 4",5,6),c(7,8,"<"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to remove (e.g. convert to NA) those elements that contain the character “<”. I could do this by columns or rows with grep(). Can this be done in the whole dataframe at once? (one liner preferred)

Comment: Just convert the dataframe to numeric. `DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.numeric)`. All the non-numeric arguments would be automatically converted to `NA`.

Comment: This works nicely in this specific case, but would also delete all non-numeric values in a data frame. If this would have been an answer, I would have voted you up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-liner given by @Ronak in his comment above may be the easiest and most graceful way to proceed here.  That being said, if you need to search for specific strings to replace with `NA`, then here is base R option:

```
data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) { ifelse(grepl(".*<.*", x), NA, x) }))
```

This would replace each entry in the data frame containing `<` anywhere with `NA`, and you can easily extend to handle any pattern as it uses `grepl`.

Comment: This approach also has the benefit of not generating warnings.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

DF2 <- DF %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(grepl("<", .), NA, .))
DF2
  c.1....2...NA. c....4...5..6. c.7..8......
1              1           <NA>            7
2           <NA>              5            8
3           <NA>              6         <NA>
```

Or a solution from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)

DF2 <- DF %>% map_dfc(~ifelse(grepl("<", .), NA, .))
DF2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  c.1....2...NA. c....4...5..6. c.7..8......
           <chr>          <chr>        <chr>
1              1           <NA>            7
2           <NA>              5            8
3           <NA>              6         <NA>
```

Or a solution from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DF2 <- setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(grepl("<", x), NA, x))]
DF2
   c.1....2...NA. c....4...5..6. c.7..8......
1:              1             NA            7
2:             NA              5            8
3:             NA              6           NA
```